# What are the differences between 的,地 and 得?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to understand the differences between the three (de) in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

let me answer the question you asked:
Firstly, I assume you are an English speaker.
的,地 and 得 are three very basic linking words in Chinese.

---

**'的'** is used follows attributes which are the adjectives you called.
For instance:
In English: `She  is   a   lovely  girl.`
In Chinese:  `她  是  一位  漂亮的  女孩。`
So, you can notice that 'lovely' substituted by '漂亮的' in Chinese.

---

**'地'** is used follows attributes as adverbs.
For instance:
In English: `He drives carefully.`
In Chinese:`他 小心地 开车。`
The 'carefully' is replaced by '小心地'

---

**'得'** often express the meaning of degree and possibility.  It is very complex to use and even the native speaker can make a fault.

Considering you are a learner, I recommend you to memorize this structure:
verb + 得 + a sentence
in the structure above, 得 is very similar to 'so that'
For instance:
English:`I'm    so tired that     I can't walk anymore.`
Chinese: `我    累得               走不动路了`
It linked the relationship between 'can't walk anymore' and 'tired'.

It can also express the possibility:
English:`The floor needs    mopping.`
Chinese:`地板      得       拖了`
In another word, 得 can replace 'need' and this a very idiomatic Chinese phraseology. I highly recommend you to replace '需要' terms of '得' in oral Chinese.

---

If you keep any questions, just ask. I'm very glad to help you.

Comment: 谢谢你！I am actually Spanish, but love languages. What about the use of 的 as possesive article? How does that work?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not a Chinese teacher and do not sure what a possesive article is. Give me some examples so that I can answer you better  : )

Comment: It makes reference to ownership, like 爸爸的钱 (dad's money)

Comment: Got you, It can't be more simple to answer. You can definitely consider the " 's " as '的' added after a noun as the possessive article and never make fault. : )

Comment: It also can be used as a nominal possessive pronoun, such as in '这些钱是我爸爸的' and '这些东西是他的', those equal to 'of my dad' and 'his'.

Comment: Here is the form of the nominal possessive pronoun.我的='mine'，我们的='ours'，他的='yours'，他们的='yours'，她的='hers'，她们的='theirs'，它的='its'，它们的='theirs'。